# php form upload does not assign any permissions to the uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, joomla1.5, file-permissions, permission-denied

hi everyone I am customizing a real estate component in joomla 1.5 part of the functionality of that component is that the site administrator can upload a pdf to go alongside the description of the individual real estate item in exactly the same way that the script to upload a picture of the item works.  Thing is though the form uploads the script but people browsing the site cant actually see it.  They click the link and get a 403 forbidden error.  The web server can see the file but no one has any permission to view it.  I've checked the permissions on the folder which contains the pdfs and they are fine (755).  I've checked permissions on the pdf which was uploaded and sometimes they show as no permissions at all in Dreamweaver and at other times they show as 644 or 600.  I did think of trying to incorporate the chmod command in there somewhere but I am working with joomla and a lot of the code is joomla specific which makes it difficult to see clearly what's going on.  Can you guys help me out and show me where I am going wrong.  The code is below:

Many Thanks

```
 <?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
# com_properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# author Fabio Esteban Uzeltinger
# copyright Copyright (C) 2011 com-property.com. All Rights Reserved.
# @license - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
# Websites:  www.com-property.com
# Technical Support: www.com-property.com/forum-v4
*/
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 
$TableName = 'pdfs';
$component_name = 'properties';
JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function submitbutton(pressbutton) {
    var form = document.adminForm;
    /*var type = form.type.value;*/

    if (pressbutton == 'cancel') {
        submitform( pressbutton );
        return;
    }
    if ( document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        alert( "Item must have a Title" );
    }
                else if( document.getElementById('parent').value == 0 ){
        alert( "Please select a Product" );
    }           
 else {
        submitform( pressbutton );
    }
}
//-->


function jSelectProperty(id, title, object) {
            document.getElementById(object + '_id').value = id;
            document.getElementById(object + '_name').value = title;            
            document.getElementById('parent').value = id;           
            document.getElementById('sbox-window').close();
        }

</script>

<?php
require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers'.DS.'menu_left.php' );
?>
<table class="admintable" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="200px" valign="top">
<?php echo MenuLeft::ShowMenuLeft();?>

        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="td_form">


<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col100">
    <fieldset class="adminform2">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'Add Pdf' ); ?></legend>
            <table>
                <tr>        
                    <td width="50%" >
                        <table>

                        <tr>
    <td class="paramlist_key" width="40%">
        <span class="editlinktip">
            <label id="urlparamsid-lbl" for="urlparamsid" class="hasTip">
                <?php echo JText::_( 'Parent Product' ); ?>
            </label>
        </span>
    </td>

    <td class="paramlist_value">


<?php
require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'elements'.DS.'property.php' );
$node=null;
$control_name='';
echo JElementProperty::fetchElement('parent', $this->datos->parent, &$node, $control_name);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="parent" id="parent" value="<?php echo $this->datos->parent;?>" />
    </td>
</tr>



                            <tr>
                                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                                <label for="name">
                                <?php echo JText::_( 'Nombre' ); ?>:
                                </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input class="text_area" type="text" name="name" id="name" style="width:270px;" size="60" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->datos->name;?>" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>            
                                <td class="key">
                                <label for="name">
                                <?php echo JText::_( 'Published' ); ?>:
                                </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
<?php $chequeado0 = $this->datos->published ? JText::_( '' ) : JText::_( 'checked="checked"' );?>
<?php $chequeado1 = $this->datos->published ? JText::_( 'checked="checked"' ) : JText::_( '' );?>


<?php if($this->datos->published==''){
$chequeado1=JText::_( 'checked="checked"' );$chequeado0=JText::_( '' );}?>   

    <input name="published" id="published1" value="1" <?php echo $chequeado1;?> type="radio">
    <label for="published1"><?php echo JText::_( 'Yes' ); ?></label>  
    <input name="published" id="published0" value="0" <?php echo $chequeado0;?> type="radio">
    <label for="published0"><?php echo JText::_( 'No' ); ?></label> 
                            </td>
                            </tr>       
                            <tr>
                                <td class="key">
                                <label for="name">
                                <?php echo JText::_( 'Ordering' ); ?>:
                                </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input class="text_area" type="text" name="ordering" id="ordring"  style="width:72px;" size="20" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $this->datos->ordering; ?>" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>                                          

                            <tr>
                                <td class="key">                
                                <?php echo JText::_( 'Archivo' ); ?>                        
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <?php 
                                if($this->datos->archivo){ ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo JURI::root().'images/properties/pdfs/'.$this->datos->parent.'/'.$this->datos->archivo; ?>" target="_blank">
                            <?php echo $this->datos->archivo; 

                                }?>
                            </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                <input type="file" size="20" name="archivo" value=""/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
            </table>
            <table class="admintable" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php $editor = &JFactory::getEditor();     
                    echo $editor->display('text', $this->datos->text, '100%', '400', '60', '20');
                    ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>


<div class="clr"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php echo $TableName; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->datos->id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="<?php echo $TableName; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="<?php echo $TableName; ?>" />
</form>
    </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
```

Form Processing Script

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
# com_properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# author Fabio Esteban Uzeltinger
# copyright Copyright (C) 2011 com-property.com. All Rights Reserved.
# @license - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
# Websites:  www.com-property.com
# Technical Support: www.com-property.com/forum-v4
*/
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class PropertiesControllerPdfs extends PropertiesController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->registerTask( 'add'  ,   'edit' );
        $this->registerTask( 'apply',   'save' );
        $this->registerTask('save2new',     'save');
        $this->registerTask( 'unpublish',   'publish'); 
    }

    function display()
    {
        parent::display();
    }   

    function edit()
    {
        JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'pdfs' );
        JRequest::setVar( 'layout', 'form' );       
        parent::display();
    }

    function save()
    {
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $this->TableName='pdfs';
    global $mainframe;
    $component_name = 'properties';
    $option = JRequest::getVar('option');
    $model = $this->getModel('pdfs');
    $post = JRequest::get( 'post' );
    $db     =& JFactory::getDBO();
    require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'configuration.php');
    $datos = new JConfig(); 
    $basedatos = $datos->db;
    $dbprefix = $datos->dbprefix;
    $query = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `".$basedatos."` LIKE '".$dbprefix.$component_name."_".$this->TableName."';";
        $db->setQuery( $query );        
        $nextAutoIndex = $db->loadObject();

    if(JRequest::getVar('id')){ $id_archivo = JRequest::getVar('id');
    }else{$id_archivo = $nextAutoIndex->Auto_increment;}

    if($_FILES['archivo']['name']) {    

    // Set FTP credentials, if given
        jimport('joomla.client.helper');
        JClientHelper::setCredentialsFromRequest('ftp');

    $path = JPATH_SITE.DS.'images'.DS.'properties'.DS.'pdfs'.DS.$post['parent'].DS;

    if(!JFolder::exists($path))
        {
        JFolder::create($path,0755);
        }

        $ext =  JFile::getExt($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
        $filename = $post['name'].'.'.$ext;
        $move_to=$path.$filename;

if(JFolder::move($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $move_to)) 
    {       
    chmod ($filename,0755);
    $post['archivo'] = $filename;
    }
    }

    $text = JRequest::getVar( 'text', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );        
    $post['text'] = $text;

    $datenow =& JFactory::getDate();
    $post['date'] = $datenow->toFormat("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S");

    if ($model->store($post)) { 
    $msg =  JText::_( 'Saved').' ( '.$post['name'].' ) ';

    switch (JRequest::getCmd( 'task' ))
        {
            case 'apply':
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_properties&view=pdfs&layout=form&task=edit&cid[]='.$id_archivo);
                break;
            case 'save':
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_properties&view=pdfs');
                break;              
            case 'save2new':
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_properties&view=pdfs&layout=form&task=edit', false));
    $msg.=JText::_('You can add new Product.');
                break;                  
        }       

        } else {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Error Saving Greeting' );
            $msg .=  'err'.$this->Err;
        }   
        $this->setMessage( JText::_( $msg ) );  
    }


    function remove()
    {
    //echo 'remove';
    $model = $this->getModel('pdfs');
        if(!$model->delete()) {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Error: One or More Greetings Could not be Deleted' );
        } else {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Deleted' ) ;
        }
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_properties&view=pdfs',$msg);  
    }

    function cancel()
    {
    $this->TableName = JRequest::getCmd('table');
        $msg = JText::_( 'Operation Cancelled' );
        //$this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_properties&table='.$this->TableName, $msg );
        parent::display();
    }   



}
```

Comment: not exactly helpful dude!  Yes I am using code created by a non english speaker.  It's still pretty good code though.

Comment: [Spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line (in class `PropertiesControllerPdfs`) where you try to change the permisions of the file:

```
chmod ($filename,0755);
```

to include the full path along with the file name, i,e:

```
chmod ($path.$filename,0755);
```

Comment: hi I just tried that one, but the file still shows as permissions of 600 to be honest I added that line to the code as I was trying to amend it and it is not part of the original code.  Apologies for this as I meant to take it out prior to posting.  Thanks very much for your help with this though I really am grateful for any assistance.

Comment: I saw that your initial `chmod` is inside an `if` statement. Try to execute the above command I proposed when you successfully created the file. As long as you have the file created but not with the right permissions that might be the problem

Comment: Thanks very much Pankar, superb answer to my question.  I placed the chmod function on line 76 exactly as described by yourself.  Superb Help.  I really am greateful.